# Show timeout error message after particular interval time angularjs

Tags: angularjs, settimeout

I am trying show a timeout error message after particular interval of idle time(say 10 mins)

I followed the below link and it is working as expected.
https://long2know.com/2015/04/user-session-timeout/

```
var idleService = function ($rootScope, $timeout, $log) {
var idleTimer = null,
    startTimer = function () {
        $log.log('Starting timer');
        idleTimer = $timeout(timerExpiring, 10000);
    },
    stopTimer = function () {
        if (idleTimer) {
            $timeout.cancel(idleTimer);
        }
    },
    resetTimer = function () {
        stopTimer();
        startTimer();
    },
    timerExpiring = function () {
        stopTimer();
        $rootScope.$broadcast('sessionExpiring');
        $log.log('Timer expiring ..');
    };

startTimer();

return {
    startTimer: startTimer,
    stopTimer: stopTimer,
    resetTimer: resetTimer
};
```

};

Is it possible to achieve it without the $broadcast and $on. Any guidance on how to make the controller variable know when the timeout is expired, currently it is achieved via $broadcast from service and $on on controller and then the variable will be modified in $on function.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs) to create an observable. Your controller would subscribe to it through your service and when the timeout is expired, a value is emitted on your observable (could be a void value). This way, every controller that has a subscription on that observable would receive the signal that the timeout is expired.

I did a plunker to illustrate this: https://plnkr.co/edit/JSgKWLwQLAhqgRGPn9ys

First, you start by creating a method that returns an observable. I'm using a `Subject` as you don't need to send an initial value or a value that has already been emitted:

```
var getExpiredSignal = function() {
  return subject.asObservable();
}
```

Now, when you timeout is expired, you need to send a signal through the observable by doing:

```
subject.next();
```

As your controller did subscribe to this observable via the line:

```
timeout.getExpiredSignal().subscribe(() => console.log('Expired!'));
```

The callback function logging "Expired" is triggered.

Comment: Thank you for the input.I am trying with angularjs, can you provide some input on that.

Comment: Sorry i thought we can use Rxjs in angular not in angularjs

Comment: RxJS is "just" a JavaScript library you can use even in non-angular project ;-)

Comment: It's a bit a shame to pollute the rootScope object with such variables when you can use Observables that totally fit with your needs.

Comment: hmm..ya..Thanks for your input its a new learning for me as well.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work with the below approach

```
var idleService = function ($rootScope, $timeout, $log) {
var idleTimer = null,
    startTimer = function () {
        $log.log('Starting timer');
        idleTimer = $timeout(timerExpiring, 10000);
    },
    stopTimer = function () {
        if (idleTimer) {
            $timeout.cancel(idleTimer);
        }
    },
    resetTimer = function () {
        stopTimer();
        startTimer();
    },
    timerExpiring = function () {
        stopTimer();
        $rootScope.sessionFlag = true;
        $log.log('Timer expiring ..');
    };

startTimer();

return {
    startTimer: startTimer,
    stopTimer: stopTimer,
    resetTimer: resetTimer
};
};
```

Now I am not using $broadcast and $on but I am changing the $rootscope.sessionFlag which I am referencing in my html